# Syntax error reading and reversing STDIN

Tags: perl

I'm just starting to learn Perl today by going through [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/index.html), but one of the examples is tripping me up. The book has this code:

```
while (<>)
{
  chomp;
  say scalar reverse;
}
```

Running this code with the command `perl stdin.pm  hi.txt` or `cat hi.txt | perl stdin.pm` gives me this error:

```
syntax error at stdin.pm line 4, near "say scalar"
Execution of stdin.pm aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The contents of `hi.txt` are:

```
hi
how
are
you
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [say feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html)

```
use feature `say`;
```

or use what author of the book [suggest](http://search.cpan.org/~chromatic/Modern-Perl-1.20140107/lib/Modern/Perl.pm),

```
use Modern::Perl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I actually have `use Modern::Perl;` in my other Perl scripts so far, I just forgot it in this one.